# Oracle Apex Date-picker Hide Days

Tags: oracle-apex

could you please tell me how to solve my problem?
I have a project start date and project completion date field. It should be done so that the user could not choose a completion date lower than the start date. I want it to look like when you select the current date, the days in the end date were not active if they are less than the start date. Thank you in advance!

i used options and apex but didn't find anithing

Comment: Not sure that is possible. Typically you would implement a pre-submit check on the fields to make sure they meet required values.

Comment: yes, i did it but my boss didn't take it)))

Comment: What version of APEX are you using?

Comment: @ 
pmdba 20.2  ver

Comment: Have a look here, then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76943758/oracle-apex-data-picker-hide-days-20-2

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel; Apex offers that functionality by default.

I'm on Page 7.

Navigate to `P7_END` date's **Settings** and set

- minimum date: Item
- minimum item: `P7_START`

That's all.

How does it work? Like this:

[image]