# Oracle apex data picker hide days 20.2

Tags: oracle-apex

could you please tell me how to solve my problem? I have a project start date and project completion date field. It should be done so that the user could not choose a completion date lower than the start date. I want it to look like when you select the current date, the days in the end date were not active if they are less than the start date. Thank you in advance!

i used options and apex but didn't find anything but in 23 version we have this option

Comment: did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935144/oracle-apex-date-picker-hide-days

Comment: @Oguen yes but i need this in 20.2 version

Answer (score 1):

As there's no such property in Apex 20.2, try with dynamic action.

- two date picker items: `P2_START` and `P2_END`
- create dynamic action on `P2_START`:

  - action: execute JavaScript code
  - code: `$('#P2_END').datepicker("option","minDate",$("#P2_START").val());`
- modify `P2_END` item's "minimum date" property to `&P2_START.`
- run the page

How does that look like? A little bit *awkward*; for some reason, the *calendar icon* is moved *left* but - other than that, it does what you wanted:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but yes the calendar icon is moved left((( and it became slightly modified